# Understanding Ender.js

Tags: javascript, ender

In my understanding, Ender is a command line tool that helps organize your javascript dependencies. We can use `ender build underscore qwery` to produce a `ender.js` file which contains the codes of `underscore` and `qwery`, then we can include this file in our html.
However, I noticed that `ender` gets those libs from `npm` site, so I'm worrying that if all of those libraries could be use in browser side?

Comment: What exactly is your worry? Please be more specific about that, maybe give an example.

Comment: @igorw I'm worrying that what I get with ender build might be for node.js and will not work in browsers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ender.js is a tool for JavaScript dependency management in the browser.

It uses npm for the underlying package management (basically to fetch packages), then compiles all of these fetched packages into a single minified file, that can be used by the browser.

The fact that npm is used does not mean that the packages are (only) for node. Most of them are browser-only, some of them can be used by node and the browser. Basically, there is nothing to worry about.